# Get requested URI which is displaying in browser in Apache velocity

Tags: java, velocity, tiles

I have spring + tiles + velocity integration in my project. In my velocity file I used like `$request.getRequestURI()`. But always its showing layout file name instead of requested URI which is showing in the browser. Can any one help me to get requested URI which is in browser.

How to get requested URI which is displaying in browser in Apache velocity?

Comment: Might want to ask at user@tiles.apache.org or the spring forums too.  In plain ol' Velocity, what you're doing should/would work.  Something is happening in Tiles or Spring to forward the request, i think.

Answer (score 1):

Tried this?
$request.getRequestURL()